# Linking HTML form with xampp

Tags: html, xampp

I have created a simple HTML form with two input sections, Name and age, I want to connect the form with xampp server. I have installed xampp on my PC. Can anyone help me with the procedure for linking the form with the xampp.

The form is in .html format.

Comment: why do u want to connect to server?

Comment: If you want to extract the name and age on your 'server' than you need PHP for it.

Comment: If I fill the form then the data should be in the DB, how should I do it?

Comment: @C0dekid please guide me

Comment: if u dont know php or asp then u can use xml

Answer (score 0):

**XAMPP** is a collation of applications (**apache, mysql, php and perl**) that will help you serve and process **html, php, mysql and perl** commands you send to it (otherwise known as serve a webpage).

If you're seeing your form, you're probably already using Apache to serve it (the html file you made) and probably what you want then is the *server to receive that info and save it to a database or display it onscreen, modify something, etc.*

To do that, you need to **prepare another file** (probably a PHP one, pointed out in the **action of your form**) that will **receive the post/get** data from your form and do that something with that data.

With that in mind, you should start with some basic PHP form crash course or with [W3 Schools PHP Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) or [PHP Manual Tutorial about Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the name and the age, you need to use PHP on your XAMPP 'server'. Create two files `index.html` and `welcome.php` in your XAMP htdocs folder.

Your `index.html` file should have (Reffering to the fieldnames from your question):

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
    <button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The 'action' will tell that form where you should post to. So in this example we going to post the data to `welcome.php`.

On your server you want to know what data was posted so we need to extract the POST data like  this, place the code below in `welcome.php`

```
<?php
// Check if the user hit the submit button
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    echo "Your name is {$_POST["name"]} and you are {$_POST["age"]} years old.";
}else{
    echo "We don't know your name, please enter your name. <a href='index.html'>Go back</a>";
}
?>
```

This is just the basic. I hope this will help you understanding the form.

Small demonstration:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GYvY5Ml.gif]