# edit local .json file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to edit .json file through my .js file that I created just next to it.
i am using ajax call to fetch the data from my .json file but for editing I dont know how to do that, here is my code for fetching data:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       objects =JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText) ;
      

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "object.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

this is also my .json file:

```js
{
    "circles":[
        {  "id":1 ,
            "cx":100,
            "cy":100,
            "r":50,
            "stroke":"green" ,
            "strokeWidth":4,
            "fill":"yellow"
        },
        {
            "id":2 ,
            "cx":30,
            "cy":30,
            "r":10,
            "stroke":"green" ,
            "strokeWidth":4,
            "fill":"yellow"
        }
            ]
}
```

please give me a clue
thank you guys :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from the server from the front-end, but to edit the data you need to create some backend functionality. This can be either a server or a serverless function, or a hosted db call, but you can't edit a plain .json file without a backend.

Comment: you mean i should use node.js or php ... for making a listening functionality to do that ?

Comment: I am using localhost (xammp ) for know

Comment: Ok, so if you want to stick with xammp then you're going to want to use PHP. There are alternatives to Xammp that are more modern and may be easier however.

Have a google about, but this might be a good starting point: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138287/13892264

Comment: thank you for helping 
but i wanna sure if you got it right that , two file (.json and .js) are in the same directory in my computer right next to each other ?
because it is weird to install node.js just for manipulate on file in your computer

Comment: I don't know how you've set up your server, but most webservers hy default will give write-only access.

Comment: You aren't actually running that js file on the computer that is hosting (ie storing) the Json file, the client pc is downloading the js and running the script that does a xmlhttprequest to get the Json too. Both reading from the server, but the server (for security) will not let clients just arbitrarily write or edit any files

Comment: i am check it in the server and it is work i mean i can fetch data and display it from json you can visit my site (rezayari.ir/test) you should see 2 circle display which they informations came from json file

Comment: Yeah, you can read info from a server. You not edit it though.